# python - cannot make corr work

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, correlation

I'm struggling with getting a simple correlation done. I've tried all that was suggested under similar questions.

Here are the relevant parts of the code, the various attempts I've made and their results.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

try01 = data[['ESA Index_close_px', 'CCMP Index_close_px' ]].corr(method='pearson')

print (try01)
```

Out:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

---

```
try04 = data['ESA Index_close_px'][5:50].corr(data['CCMP Index_close_px'][5:50])
print (try04)
```

Out:

```
**AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'**
```

---

### using numpy

```
try05 = np.corrcoef(data['ESA Index_close_px'],data['CCMP Index_close_px'])
print (try05)
```

Out:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

---

### converting the columns to lists

```
ESA_Index_close_px_list = list()
start_value = 1
end_value = len (data['ESA Index_close_px']) +1
for items in data['ESA Index_close_px']:
    ESA_Index_close_px_list.append(items)
    start_value = start_value+1    
    if start_value == end_value:
        break
    else:
        continue

CCMP_Index_close_px_list = list()
start_value = 1
end_value = len (data['CCMP Index_close_px']) +1
for items in data['CCMP Index_close_px']:
    CCMP_Index_close_px_list.append(items)
    start_value = start_value+1    
    if start_value == end_value:
        break
    else:
        continue

try06 = np.corrcoef(['ESA_Index_close_px_list','CCMP_Index_close_px_list'])
print (try06)
```

Out:

```
****TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type****
```

---

Also tried .astype but not made any difference.

```
data['ESA Index_close_px'].astype(float)

data['CCMP Index_close_px'].astype(float)
```

Using Python 3.5, pandas 0.18.1 and numpy 1.11.1

Would really appreciate any suggestion.

**edit1:*
Data is coming from an excel spreadsheet
`data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Ako\\Desktop\\ako_files\\for_corr_‌​tool.xlsx')`  prior to the correlation attempts, there are only column renames and

```
data = data.drop(data.index[0])
```

to get rid of a line

regarding the types:

```
print (type (data['ESA Index_close_px']))



print (type (data['ESA Index_close_px'][1]))
```

Out:

**edit2*
parts of the data:

```
print (data['ESA Index_close_px'][1:10])

print (data['CCMP Index_close_px'][1:10])
```

Out:

```
2        2137
3        2138
4        2132
5        2123
6        2127
7     2126.25
8      2131.5
9      2134.5
10       2159
Name: ESA Index_close_px, dtype: object
2     5241.83
3     5246.41
4     5243.84
5     5199.82
6     5214.16
7     5213.33
8     5239.02
9     5246.79
10    5328.67
Name: CCMP Index_close_px, dtype: object
```

Comment: Can you post some of your input data?

Comment: We need to see how you created the DataFrame `data`.  At the least, we need to know more about it, such `data.dtypes`.   I was not able to reproduce what you show in your first three examples.

Comment: Certainly:
`data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Ako\\Desktop\\ako_files\\for_corr_tool.xlsx')`
It is coming from an excel spreadsheet

prior to the correlation attempts, there are only column renames and 
`data = data.drop(data.index[0])`
to get rid of a line

regarding the types:
`print (type (data['ESA Index_close_px']))   `
`print (type (data['ESA Index_close_px'][1]))`

out:
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'float'>

Comment: We need you to edit your question and copy some data there directly. Please check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Thanks Ian
I edited the Q with the additional info. Also added to my response to Warren.
When I did:
`print (type (data['ESA Index_close_px']))` and `print (type (data['ESA Index_close_px'][1]))` I got float
however with `print (data['ESA Index_close_px'][1:10])`   it says dtype object

Answer (score 25):

Well, I've encountered the same problem today.
try use `.astype('float64')` to help make the type correct.
`data['ESA Index_close_px'][5:50].astype('float64').corr(data['CCMP Index_close_px'][5:50].astype('float64'))`

This works well for me. Hope it can help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as following:

```
Top15['Citable docs per capita']=(Top15['Citable docs per capita']*100000)
Top15['Citable docs per capita'].astype('int').corr(Top15['Energy Supply per Capita'].astype('int'))
```

It worked for me.